# Create link and url using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, copy

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="ProductCode"><span>Product number</span>2100022</div>
```

With jQuery, I want to change code to this:

```
<div id="ProductCode"><span>Product number</span><a href=”http://www.site.com/2100022”>2100022</a></div>
```

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate elements compare its [**Node.nodeType**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType), If node is `TEXT_NODE(3)`. Then use [**.replaceWith()**](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to replace the text node with anchor element

```
$('#ProductCode').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var elem = $('<a>', {
            href: "http://www.example.com/" + this.nodeValue,
            text: this.nodeValue
        });
        $(this).replaceWith(elem);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyj99/)

### EDIT

[**.wrap()**](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) is better option

```
$('#ProductCode').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var elem = $('<a>', {
            href: "http://www.example.com/" + this.nodeValue
        });
        $(this).wrap(elem);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO with wrap**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyj99/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:

$(document).ready(function(){
var span_text = $('#ProductCode span').text()
$('#ProductCode span').remove();
var year = $('#ProductCode').text()
$('#ProductCode').html('<span>'+ span_text +'</span><a href=”http://www.site.com/”' + year + '>' + year  +'</a>');
})

You can check it also here: http://jsfiddle.net/aaa_borza/5nA9J/8/.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'replaceWith' method for converting your text into a href  on page load or where ever you want but befor do this put your text into a span than use this code.
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/37/)

```
$('.link').replaceWith(function() {


  var url = $.trim($(this).text());
return '<a href="http://www.site.com/2100022" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
           });
```

html part

```
<div id="ProductCode"><span>Product number</span><span class="link">2100022</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

it will get you the product ID and wrap it on anchor tag]

```
var $root = $('#ProductCode');
var $span = $root.children('span');

$span.remove();
$root.wrapInner('<a href="http://www.site.com/'+$root.text()+'"></a>');
$root.prepend($span);
```